# Adding id to input element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add an id to an existing input element. The element I am trying to add the id to is this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" />
```

I have tried getting the element by name and add the id by doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='submit']").attr('id','btnSubmit');
});
```

However this does not appear to be working. Any suggestions?

The input field is created in backend Java code which I do not have access to. So in the jsp I am working in I just delete the input field on page load and then create a new button which solves my problem. I know its not very efficient but unfortunately I can't access the java code to just change the id there.

Comment: you need to add jquery

Comment: Code is fine, It should work, check browser console for errors!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me as well: http://jsfiddle.net/455dcqjo/

Comment: i do not see any error in this code. If you add this button after the page load, it may not work. In that case, add this code inside the create input function.

Comment: @AmmarCSE I include jquery on the page so that is not the issue

Comment: @Caleb, you say the HTML comes from a server(Java). When/how does it come? Ajax?

Answer (score -1):

As far as i remember you don´t need to specify the "input" part on the name.
Leave it just like, let´s see if that works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("[name='submit']").attr('id','btnSubmit');
});
```